# How to convert website in to iOS mobile app?

Tags: ios, iphone

We have already build a website. Is there any way to convert that website into mobile iOS app and make sure that it follows the iOS standards?

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible (easy, even) but Apple's guidelines specifically say that apps that are just repackaging of a website will be rejected, so no, your approach is a non-starter.

Comment: Yes. Display the contents in a web view.

Answer (score 0):

This can be doable using cordova as a wrapper application. But this application will be rejected by Apple. We faced same issue couple of months back, this kind of app accepted in google play but not in apple app store.